# How to find out the number of derangements for n objects?

Tags: combinatorics, derangements

Is there any simple derivation for the number of derangements of n objects?

I have the problem - the number of ways in which n men can collect their n coats,with no man getting his own coat. 
I’ve started with $n! -$ (greater than or equal to one man gets his own coat).
 But I have difficulty understanding where things are being over-counted.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show us what you know and what you have tried. What derivation do you know and what's not simple about it?

Comment: Did you check Wikipedia? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement#Counting_derangements